# How to maintain multiple run_forever handlers simultaneously?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Imagine you have a background processing daemon which could be controlled by a web interface.

So, the app is an object with some methods responsible for handling requests and one special method that needs to be called repeatedly from time to time, regardless of requests state.

When using `aiohttp`, the web part is fairly straightforward: you just instantiate an application instance, and set things up as per `aiohttp.web.run_app` source. Everything is clear. Now let's say your app instance has that special method, call it `app.process`, which is structured like so:

```
async def process(self):
    while self._is_running:
        await self._process_single_job()
```

With this approach you could call `loop.run_until_complete(app.process())`, but it blocks, obviously, and thus leaves no opportunity to set up the web part. Surely, I could have split these two responsibilities into separate processes and establish their communication by means of a database, but that would complicate things, so I would prefer to avoid this way if at all possible.

So, how do I make the event loop call some method repeatedly while still running a web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to schedule the execution of `app.process()` as a task using [loop.create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.create_task):

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web

class MyApp(web.Application):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.process_task = self.loop.create_task(self.process())
        self.on_shutdown.append(lambda app: app.process_task.cancel())

    async def process(self):
        while True:
            print(await asyncio.sleep(1, result='ping'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(MyApp())
```